# Я повторяю, я Андрей или Я повторяю. Я Андрей

Tags: запятые

Как правильнее? Я повторяю, я Андрей или же Я повторяю. Я Андрей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - Андрей!
Я повторяю: я - Андрей!